# How test API in cloud9 (lambda function)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, cloud9-ide, aws-cloud9

I'm learning to use lambda functions; i was following a tutorial but i am failing to figure out how to test the API in Cloud9. Particularly when I follow these steps

- Connect to Cloud9 by browsing to https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloud9/
- Open the Cloud9 IDE
- In the following command replace “
  https://abcdef123.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com” with your Invoke URL from the previous step to set a variable with the Invoke URL

I did not understand where to put the line

*export INVOKE_URL="https://**abcdef123**.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com"*

and

*curl -X "PUT" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{
"id": "abcdef234",
"price": 12345,
"name": "myitem"
}" $INVOKE_URL/items*

i tried to put in the console but nothing happens. Am I wrong something?

Comment: Can you please provide a link to the tutorial you are using?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein https://simple-crud-api.workshop.aws/080_test_your_api.html

Comment: Those commands are run on the command-line, or frankly anywhere that `curl` is installed. It makes an HTTP Put Request to the API Gateway endpoint.

Comment: can you kindly tell me how to do it? i use cloud9.

Comment: I'm not sure specifically about Cloud9, but it would be where ever you can run Linux commands. There should be a console window in Cloud9 where you can run commands.